Why does port 8443 work, and port 4223 doesn't?
I implemented a https server and a wss server using NetCoreServer in DotNet8.0
When i run the server(s) in a local virtualbox, and access it by its extern ip, everything works fine.
I now uploaded the server to my public internet server/machine, and suddenly, only the port 8443 works (https), the websocket server on port 4223 is not reachable, does not respond to telnet. When connecting to port 4223 by 127.0.0.1, it works, via extern ip, no response.
The result of iptables -L:
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

So there seems to be no firewall active.
The result of netstat -tlnp:
Active Internet connections (only servers) 

Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address      Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4223       0.0.0.0:*              LISTEN      1285/dotnet
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8443       0.0.0.0:*              > LISTEN      1285/dotnet

The result of telnet:
$ telnet 12.345.67.89 4223
Trying 12.345.67.89...
^C

$ telnet 12.345.67.89 8443
Trying 12.345.67.89...
Connected to 12.345.67.89.
Escape character is '^]'.

$ telnet localhost 4223
Trying ::1...
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.

Does anybody have an idea, why port 8443 works, and port 4223 doesn't? In my local virtualbox both ports work when I access them by their extern ip.
Edit: I now changed the ports so the websocket server listens on 8443, and the https server on 4223, and now i can connect to the websocket server but not to the https server.
Solved: My server provider actually has firewall rules, that i don't see in the virtual machine, but in the control panel of the vserver. Now everything works.

I now uploaded the server to my public internet server/machine where is it located? Is there any firewall in front of it (I would really hope so)?

You were right, there is a firewall in front of the server that i don't see inside the server ...


You need to check if your provider is blocking certain ports or not.
After that, check your firewall. If using ubuntu check iptables
and ufw.
If both of the above are ok, check your NetCoreServer
configuration.


My provider is not blocking any ports. iptables result is shown in the post, and ufw status says: inactive.

When i let the Websocket-server listen on 8443, it works, so the NetCoreServer works.

My server provider actually has firewall rules, that i don't see in the virtual machine, but in the control panel of the vserver.
Of course i added my wish ports to that firewall, and now everything works.
